# How can I return nodes directly and indirectly connected to a set of nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In my db I have resources tagged with tags. The tags can be within other tags (i.e. 'neo4j' would be connected to 'databases' like this: `(neo4j:tag)-[:WITHIN]->(databases:tag)` ), though not all tags have parents.

I want to be able to return resources tagged both directly and indirectly to selected tags (searching for 'databases' would return resources tagged with 'neo4j' a well).

I've tried using an optional match, but it's not working as expected.

```
MATCH (re:resource)-[:TAGGED_WITH]->(child:tag) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (parent:tag)<-[:WITHIN_TAG]-(:tag)<-[:TAGGED_WITH]-(re) 
WHERE child.uid IN {includedTags} OR parent.uid IN {includedTags}
RETURN re
```

Included tags is an array of tag ids.

I've also tried something more like the following, but it seems that it only returns resources tagged with only tags that have parents.

`OPTIONAL MATCH (parent:tag)<-[:WITHIN_TAG]-(:tag)<-[:TAGGED_WITH]-(re:resource)-[:TAGGED_WITH]->(child:tag)`

Any suggestions or ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should work:

```
MATCH (re:resource)-[:TAGGED_WITH]->(:tag)<-[:WITHIN_TAG*0..]-(u:tag)
WHERE u.uid IN {includedTags}
RETURN DISTINCT re;
```

The variable-length pattern `(:tag)<-[:WITHIN_TAG*0..]-(u:tag)` will match paths with 0 or more `WITHIN_TAG` relationships, and start and end with `tag` nodes. For 0-length paths, the start and end nodes will actually be the same node.

*Caveat: You should actually use a reasonable upper bound for the variable-length path (e.g., `[:WITHIN_TAG*0..5]`), or else your query may never finish or run out of memory.*

Comment: This is great! Thanks a lot. It seems the :WITHIN_TAG relationship needs to be pointing the other way though.

Comment: One undesired effect of doing it this way is adding more search tags expands the number of results rather than reduces it. Can you think of a way of returning nodes that match all (or most...) tags rather than any?